# How to sort a vector with given column only on a triplet value?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, lambda, function-object

I have a struct with three `int` in it.

```
struct x{
int a,
    b,
    c;
};
```

I am using the struct to store triplets in the vector as the triplets will represent `source`, `destination` and `weight`.

```
vector<x> myVec;
```

and I am adding values in it with `myVec.push_back({a, b, c});`

So far so good, but I want to sort them according to their weights, that'd be `c` variable. I am unsure how to use `std::sort` on my vector.

Comment: Note, this could easily be `std::tuple`.

Comment: If you do have a `struct`, write a custom comparator, `operator<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression as for example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// ...

std::sort( std::begin( myVec ), std::end( myVec ),
           []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
           {
               return a.c < b.c;
           } );
```

You can define the lambda expression object directly in the call of `std::sort`  as it has been shown above or separately as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct x{
int a,
    b,
    c;
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<x> myVec =
    {
        { 2, 2, 2 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 3, 3, 3 }
    };
    
    for ( const auto &item : myVec )
    {
        std::cout << item.a << ' ' << item.b << ' ' << item.c << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    auto compare_by_weight = []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
    {
        return a.c < b.c;
    };
    
    std::sort( std::begin( myVec ), std::end( myVec ), compare_by_weight );
    
    for ( const auto &item : myVec )
    {
        std::cout << item.a << ' ' << item.b << ' ' << item.c << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 2 2
1 1 1
3 3 3

1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Another approach is to define a function object. For example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct x{
int a,
    b,
    c;
};

struct compare_by_weight
{
    bool operator ()( const x &a, const x &b ) const
    {
        return a.c < b.c;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<x> myVec =
    {
        { 2, 2, 2 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 3, 3, 3 }
    };
    
    for ( const auto &item : myVec )
    {
        std::cout << item.a << ' ' << item.b << ' ' << item.c << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    std::sort( std::begin( myVec ), std::end( myVec ), compare_by_weight() );
    
    for ( const auto &item : myVec )
    {
        std::cout << item.a << ' ' << item.b << ' ' << item.c << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 2 2
1 1 1
3 3 3

1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```